# Odoo 8 declare view file programmatically

Tags: odoo-8

I want to declare my view file that its struct is loaded from database. I know in order I have to declare it on **openerp**.py file. But I have many user, and I want each of theme when access to my module (form view - for instance) will have difference view (fields), I am mentions to fields on database, not by "how to hide some fields for some user?". Is there any solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Field Access Right.

As of OpenERP 7.0, you can create field level access rights. You can achieve this by adding the groups attribute in your field definition in the module:

```
_columns = { 'my_field': fields.char('My field', groups="base.group_erp_manager,base.group_system") }`
```

It's still valid in Odoo 8. Check Odoo documentation about security
[https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html](http://Odoo%20Documentation)

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am not looking for a way to hide some fields to some users or groups. Anyway, thanks for your soon answer

Comment: Well, can you explain more your requirement?

Comment: Well, I want my view's struct is loaded from database.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution I'm thinking of but haven't try it yet:

Override `_views_get_fnc` in `'ir.actions.act_window'` model. This function return {action_id: (view_id, view_mode)}. Here you can query for view_id based on the user.